# How to use ViewBag in a using statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use the ViewBag to display the action for a form in a partial page.

I have tried the following:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(ViewBag.Action, "Person", FormMethod.Post)
@using(Html.BeginForm((ViewBag.Action), "Person", FormMethod.Post)
@using(Html.BeginForm(@(ViewBag.Action), "Person", FormMethod.Post)
@using(Html.BeginForm({ViewBag.Action}, "Person", FormMethod.Post)
```

But none of those work.  What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
@using(Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.Action, "Person", FormMethod.Post)
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `ViewBag` is of type `dynamic`, so therefore `ViewBag.Action` is also of type `dynamic` -- at least, that's what the compiler thinks it is.

So casting it to string will provide the missing information to the compiler.  If it's not actually a string then you get a runtime exception, but at least the code will compile correctly:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.Action, "Person", FormMethod.Post)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please don't use this ViewBag/ViewData as they transform your views into spaghetti. @Microsoft why did you ever introduced this notion? Please remove/forbid/throw a `BadCodeException` in ASP.NET MVC v4 when when a developer tries to use it.

View models are so much better/safer/strongly typed/avoiding magic strings/refactor friendlier/just working/...:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(Model.Action, "Person", FormMethod.Post)
{

}
```

Comment: `ViewBag` is not meant as a substitute for models. Instead, it's meant as a more convenient syntaxt to replace `ViewData["Property"]`.

Comment: @marcind, I see absolutely no usage for ViewBag. I mean OK, instead of `ViewData["foo"]` you write `ViewBag.foo`, but it suffers from the same bad characteristics a ViewData does: magic strings, cannot be refactored, need to cast to proper type, turns views into a mess, ... And not only this, but I think that it brings more confusion among developers. Please, remove/deprecate it in v4. It's a cry for help, really :-) I am sick of seeing it. I do many code reviews and still see so many developers use `ViewData/ViewBag`. I have no words to express my hatred towards those constructs.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately this feature is unlikely to change any time soon. And it does have a use, for example when communicating between a content page and a layout page (at least in Razor).

Comment: @marcind, could you elaborate on the usage of ViewBag for communicating between a content page and a layout page in Razor, because I've never really used it in my applications (OK, I must admit I used it to define the title of a content page `ViewBag.Title = "foo"`, but quite honestly Razor @sections could have worked just great for this simple scenario)? I mean, is ViewBag something used internally by the Razor view engine and without which it couldn't work?

Comment: That is the scenario I was talking about. The internal plumbing of view pages does not depend on ViewData.

Comment: @marcind, I am more than happy with `@section/<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ...>` which addresses this scenario fine. I am really considering for building a custom MVC build to my fellow developers where the indexer property of ViewData would throw a `CatastrophicCodeException` :-)